# React re-evaluate useRef if props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

A Child component has got an array of ref who depend of parent props. I would like to update the ref list if props change without rerender my child component.

```js
const childComponent = (props) =>
{
  // the array of ref item list
  const itemsRef = Array.from({ length: props.menuItems.length }, a => 
  useRef(null));

  useLayoutEffect(()=>
  {
   // enter anim new item ref...

  },[props.menuItem])


  return <ul>
    {props.menuItems.map((el,i) => 
      <li 
        key{i} 
        ref={itemsRef[i]}
        children={el.name}
     >}
  </ul>

}
```

`itemsRef` is not recalculate if parent updated pass a new list of menuItem by props.

How achieve this with hooks?

Comment: What your doing here seems a little mixed up,  I would personally just make each menuItem into another Component for rendering.  Also there is nothing in this component that will trigger a redraw, you have no state.

Comment: your assumption `itemsRef is not recalculate if parent updated pass a new list of menuItem` is wrong, you will get a new array each time the component is rerender, you can add a `console.log` to check it

Comment: the problem comes from you are breaking the rules of the hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions** calling `useRef` inside map is not valid

Comment: @OlivierBoissé you're right, my question is a little bit confiuse. My component is rerender but I have got a big error console message when new props is passed to ma chield component : `React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by...`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé If y can't call useRef inside a loop, how to get a list of DOM items ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**

A solution could be to use `useRef` to declare an [instance variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) which will be an array and use the `ref callback` to populate the elements in this array :

```
const childComponent = props => {
   const itemsRef = useRef([]);
   // you can access the elements with itemsRef.current[n]

   return (
     <ul>
        {props.menuItems.map((el,i) => 
          <li 
            key={i} 
            ref={el => itemsRef.current[i] = el}
            children={el.name}
          />
        }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

If you don't want null values in the array, you can add an effect to keep the array length in sync with `props.menuItems` length  (the effect will be called **after** the refs callbacks)

```
useEffect(() => {
  itemsRef.current = itemsRef.current.slice(0, props.menuItems.length);
}, [props.menuItems]);
```

Comment: thanks, this is working! The only problem is if itemsRef contain 3 items a the first render `[li.ScrollMenu_item, li.ScrollMenu_item, li.ScrollMenu_item]` and items props change to only one item, `itemsRef` return `[li.ScrollMenu_item, null, null]`. To use it correcty you have to do something like that : `itemsRef.current.filter(el => el !== null)`

Comment: it depends if the null values are a problem. As refs callbacks are called before useEffect, you could add an effect to filter the array when `props.menuItems` change. I edited my answer